# Assigning a value to a variable from another variable in SSIS (Properties -> Expression)

Tags: sql, variables, ssis, expression, assign

I have a SSIS task that will assign a value from a variable (@[User::strLgtyInst]) to another variable (@[User::LgtyPer]). This is what I have:

```
SET '" +  @[User::LgtyPer] +"' =  (SELECT [CUR_PRD_DATE] 
FROM [Log_DP_Ctrl].[Ma].[Log_CUR_PRD] 
WHERE [L_Instance] =  '" +  @[User::strLgtyInst] +"'')
```

When I evaliate the expression, it gives me this error:

Expression cannot be evaluated.

The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_DATE" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Attempt to set the result type of binary operation ""SET '" + @[User::LgtyPeriod]" failed with error code 0xC0047080.

So...
Error 1: Have to cast the variable being read. -> Please help with the syntax.
Error 2: SET... -> Don't know if that syntax is right.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set your SSIS variable the way you have tried to do since you are running a SQL query to set it. You will need to use an Execute SQL Task . Here are the steps.

1. Create a Variable @[User::SQLStatement] and in the expressions paste this  -
   "SELECT [CUR_PRD_DATE] 
   FROM [Log_DP_Ctrl].[Ma].[Log_CUR_PRD] 
   WHERE [L_Instance] =  '" + (DT_WSTR, 50) @[User::strLgtyInst] +"'"
2. In your Execute SQL Task, select SQL source type as "Variable" and set the Source variable as User::SQLStatement. Set the ResultSet property to Single Row.
3. In the Result Set tab map CUR_PRD_DATE to @[User::strLgtyInst]

Hope this helps, let me know incase you have any additional questions.

Comment: I got an error. The @[User::strLgtyInst] variable is of type datetime, and [CUR_PRD_DATE], that is retrieved with the expression in "@[User::SQLStatement]", is also datetime.
This Is the error:

Comment: Error at Pkg_Fcst_Snapshot: The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_DATE" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.
Error at Pkg_Fcst_Snp: Attempt to set the result type of binary operation ""SELECT '" + @[User::LgtyPeriod]" failed with error code 0xC0047080.

Help please.

Comment: Cast it as String - Updated in answer

Comment: @user1330343 Still having troubles?

Comment: Hi, sorry, it took so long. This is my expression to convert datetime to string in th expression builder, but it's not working.

    "SELECT  SUBSTRING((DT_STR, 30, 1252) [CUR_PRD_DATE], 1, 19 )  
    FROM [Logility_DP_Ctrl].[Maintenance].[Logility_CUR_PRD] 
 WHERE [Lgty_Instance] =  '" + @[User::strLgtyInstance] +"'"

Comment: I meant cast @[User::strLgtyInstance] to String. This should not give you an error - "SELECT [CUR_PRD_DATE]  FROM [Logility_DP_Ctrl].[Maintenance].[Logility_CUR_PRD] WHERE [Lgty_Instance] = '" + (DT_WSTR, 50) @[User::strLgtyInst] +"'"

Comment: I changed the expression to:

    "SELECT [CUR_PRD_DATE] FROM [Log_DP_Ctrl].[Ma].[Log_CUR_PRD] WHERE  
    [L_Instance] = '" + (DT_WSTR, 50) @[User::strLgtyInst] +"'"

Also I changed the data type of the variable receiving the result of this query to String, but the value is not passed when the variable with the result is used as data for a column.

Comment: Whats the result set property for the Execute SQL task set as?

Comment: In General tab: Single row
In Result Set tab: Result Name->LgtyPrdRslt, Variable Name-> User::LgtyPrd

Comment: Result name should be CUR_PRD_DATE unless you changed the query.

Comment: I changed that, and the errors I get from the progress report are:

[Extract data from LT [299]] Error: There was an error with output column "CUR_PRD_DATE" (1736) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (310). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Comment: [Extract data from LT [299]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "output column "CUR_PRD_DATE" (1736)" failed because error code 0xC0209072 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "CUR_PRD_DATE" (1736)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Extract data from LT" (299) returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Set the data type for @[User::strLgtyInst] as DateTime and see if that helps.